# Joint Probability Mass Function of Rock, Paper and Scissors

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Problem**

> A game of Rock, Paper, Scissors is usually played with $2$ people, but it can be extended to an arbitrarily large number of $n$ people, where $n\geq2$.
>
> - *If when 'all $n$ people reveal their play' **and** 'only one or all three options appear', that round is deemed **indecisive**, and they just play again.*
> - *If when 'all $n$ people reveal their play' **and** 'two of the three options appear', that round is **decisive**, and those with the winning play continue and those with the losing play are eliminated.*
> - Playing continues until only one person remains.
>
> Assume the game begins with $10$ players, each of whom independently and randomly choose between the three options with equal probability, and let $R, P$, and $S$ count the number of players who play Rock, Paper, and Scissors, respectively. Compute the Joint Probability Mass Function of $R, P$, and $S$.

**My Approach**
Let $R = r, S = s, \text{ and } P = p$. Then,

$$\boxed{P(R = r, S = s, P = p) = {}^{10}C_r\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^r\cdot{}^{10-r}C_p\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^p\cdot{}^{10-r-p}C_s\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^s}$$

This can be modified as
$$\boxed{\frac{10}{s! r! p!} \cdot \bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^{10}}$$

However, I feel like I am missing a step here. Can someone please guide?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of that first paragraph is "flavor text", i.e. (possibly) interesting but has no effect on the final answer.

Comment: If the question is asking specifically about the first round, then your approach is fine (except you are missing a factorial in the numerator $10$). There are $3^{10}$ equally-likely possible choices that the 10 people can make, and $\binom{10}{r,s,p} = \frac{10!}{s! r! p!}$ of them have $s,r,p$ scissors, rocks, and papers respectively.